# Configure LAMP webserver in a LAN

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, webserver, lamp

i want configure a lamp webserver to show a webpage only to the others host connected on the LAN. We can suppose that the ip on the lamp server is: 192.168.2.4 and i want that if a host goes on 192.168.2.4 the server shows a webpage only if the host is connected in LAN.

What i need to set?

Answer (score 1):

In the virtual host file i.e /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default, you can mention the IP's which you want to allow. Search for 'Allow From' section in the file and edit the IPs you want to add. Don't forget to restart apache2 server by 
    sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

If that pc or server only has private ip you shouldnt configure anything, but if that pc or server has public ip you could create a virtual interface (if you use linux) and configure the virtual host with that interface

Comment: Ok, i have a public ip. I use ubuntu 12.4 LTS. I don't understand why i need to create a virtual interface, i can't configure directly the virtual host?

Comment: If you have public ip everybody could visit your site, because is public. Whem you have private ip only your lan could see the site.